# Is there a way to set the cardinality of a field on a per bundle basis?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm creating a bunch of paragraph types with a node entity_reference field, in some cases, I want field_article allow 3 items, in some to allow 5 items and in some to be unlimited.

I'd like to set the cardinality of field_articles on a per bundle basis, so I don't have to create field_3_articles, field_5_articles as well.

Is there an easy way to set the cardinality on a per bundle basis for a field?

It looks like there's a core issue for this:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1029298

Comment: As far as I know, cardinality is a sitewide setting for a field, not instanced. I am not sure if any contrib module has tried to tackle this (I am with you though, field instances _should_ allow cardinality differences).

Comment: See Wims comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1029298#comment-12678935

Comment: I tried to just add a constraint that set the required number for the field to 5, but it was firing when I clicked the "add More" button on the field.  I might be able to add the constraint at the bundle level, but that may be more work than I want to do, when I could just add another field.

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but this is the reason why I create separate fields for different bundles. The idea of sharing fields makes a lot of sense on paper, but in practice I always seem to bump into issues like this one...